# 'npx create-react-app my-app' (Not able to create app)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to create a react app through npx but facing an error mentioned below. I am using the following command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Below is the error message

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND <br>
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo<br>
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND<br>
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND yourproxy<br>
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the<br>
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'       

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: .
```

[image]

Comment: See react docs https://react.dev/ they have killed create-react-app and are recommending to use nextjs remix js or gatsby js

Comment: what node version and npm version are you using?

Comment: node: v18.15.0   npm: 9.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

After that run again `npx create-react-app my-app`

Answer (score 0):

Check you internet connection and if you setup proxy in your system fix it